# How to use destructuring assignment with let

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, object-destructuring

I would like to use `let` together with ES6 syntax, such as:

```
let results
let error;
try {
    { results } = getResults();
} catch (err) {
    error = err;
}
return results;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: let IS ES6 syntax...? You're asking if it's possible to use ES6 syntax with ES6 syntax?...

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: It is possible but you need to put in in brackets like so `( { results } = getResults();)` and of course don't forget semicolon after you `let result;` above.

Comment: Protip: `try { return getResults().results; } catch(error) { … }` doesn't need any variable declarations